# SQL Server INNER JOIN with three tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following table structure :

**News** (Id_news, news_name)

**Comments** (Id_comment(PK),Id_news(FK), comment)

**Replies**(Id_Reply(PK), Id_Comment(FK), reply)

---

I want to get the number of replies to comments in the news.

This is the query I've tried.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (News INNER JOIN Comments ON News.Id_news = Commnets.Id_Comment)
INNER JOIN Reply ON Commnets.Id_Comment = Reply.Id_Comment
WHERE News.Id_news = {0}
```

This this the following situation: I have a web pages with a lot of news, but not all the news have comments and not all the comments have replies. So I need to count if there is any reply in a specific news (e.g. Id_news = 43), to run one code or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you want to have a count of replies for any particular news which may or may not have any comment or reply. Here is my try

```
SELECT COUNT(Replys.Id_Reply)
FROM NEWS  
LEFT JOIN Coments  ON Coments.ID_News = Coments.Id_News AND NEWS.Id_News = {0}
LEFT JOIN Replys  ON Replys.Id_Comment = Coments.Id_Comment
```

**Sample code to try**

```
CREATE TABLE NEWS (Id_news INT, news_name varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE Coments (Id_comment INT,Id_news INT, comment varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE Replys(Id_Reply INT, Id_Comment INT , reply varchar(10))

INSERT INTO NEWS VALUES (1,'News1'), (2, 'News2'), (3,'News3')
INSERT INTO Coments VALUES (1,1,'Comment1'), (2,1,'Comment2'), (3,2,'Comment3')
INSERT INTO Replys VALUES (1,1,'Reply1'),(2,3,'Reply2'), (3,3,'Reply3')
```

**Query**:

```
DECLARE @NewId INT = 2
SELECT COUNT(Id_Reply)
FROM NEWS N 
LEFT JOIN Coments C ON C.ID_News = N.Id_News AND N.Id_News = @NewId
LEFT JOIN Replys R ON R.Id_Comment = C.Id_Comment
```

Check on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5a59/8)

Comment: After doing some tests, this Count is counting every reply in every news. For I have 3 different news with 3 different comment/replys and is returning me 9, instead of 3.

Comment: @Veslor Give me a minute, I am checking it

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me. Can you provide me a example where you are facing issue? This query is calculating a reply count for any particular news id. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0175/1

Comment: Can you give me a scenario by editing this ?? 
 
INSERT INTO NEWS VALUES (1,'News1'), (2, 'News2'), (3,'News3')
INSERT INTO Coments VALUES (1,1,'Comment1'), (2,3,'Comment2'), (3,3,'Comment3')
INSERT INTO Replys VALUES (1,1,'Reply1'),(2,2,'Reply2'), (3,3,'Reply3')

Comment: In this example 
INSERT INTO Coments VALUES (1,1,'Comment1'), (2,3,'Comment2'), (3,3,'Comment3')
INSERT INTO Replys VALUES (1,1,'Reply1'),(2,2,'Reply2'), (3,3,'Reply3')

There are 2 comments attached to news3 and both comments have 1 reply each. That's why the count is 2 . Correct me if I am assuming wrong.

Comment: You are completely correct, I messed it up, Yes there are 2 replys in that news. Still my query doesnt work in my asp.net project, well it works but it returns what I've told you. I will check it again but there is no much to look.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasted your time, it was all correct, I made a silly sintax mistake, thats why it wouldnt work on my project. Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT   News.Id_news,COUNT(*)
FROM    News 
JOIN    Comments 
    ON  News.Id_news = Commnets.Id_news
JOIN    Reply       
    ON  Commnets.Id_Comment = Reply.Id_Comment
WHERE   News.Id_news = {0}
group by News.Id_news,Commnets.Id_Comment
```

Comment: that first join should be news.id_news = comments.id_news. Maybe also left joins to get something back even if no comments/replies

Answer (score 0):

I think your joining on to the wrong id in your first JOIN.  Try

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    News JOIN Comments ON News.Id_news = Commnets.Id_news
        JOIN Reply ON Commnets.Id_Comment = Reply.Id_Comment
WHERE 
    News.Id_news = {0}
```